# Getting 3D info from a shape file

Tags: 3d

I downloaded a data set for Long Island, NY.
Usually I don't have trouble using shape files and their 3D data to export them for use in 3Ds Max, but in this case, even though the data seems to be there, I can't seem to be able to use it. (I'm a rookie).

I tried reprojecting the layer without success.

Do you see 3D data in this file?
Could you point me in the right direction?

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoJEG8ib7Yy7hmJbKFx0yDAgjpa8?e=qtOchq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Z values are 0 in your file (`ElevContour.shp`). However, the attribute table of the file has field `ContourEle` containing the elevation of contours.

I don't know about 3Ds Max. You can set `ContourEle` value as Z Value In [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) ([direct download link for LTR version](https://qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.16.6-1-Setup-x86_64.exe)) using "Processing Toolbox <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd>  > Vector Geometry > Set Z value tool".

Set the options as in the image:

[image]

Exaggerated result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! That answers my question. 
Do you know why each contour line is miles away from each other?  Is there a multiplier or I'd need to edit the raw data in excel to remove zeros?

Comment: At the moment, I think the easiest way for you is to use this way. You don't need to remove zeros in excel. "Set Z Value" tool converts 0 into the related  elevation value in the table.

Comment: Where did you set the multiplier?
This is what I have in Autocad (see link below exported from QGIS):
As you can see in the image below, each contour line was set at a huge distance from each other. I'm not getting the same result as you.
What was your workflow after the "Set Z Value" conversion?


https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoJEG8ib7Yy7hmNjrC-ieIJrG2zb?e=RCokeu

Comment: @MrPepeLepeu I used GlobalMapper to create 3D view.

Comment: After I set the Z value the way you showed, I did a "save features as..." in QGIS and exported to a DXF. The file has 3D data now but the distance between contour lines is too big. Any idea why? Should I post a new question? 

See file here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoJEG8ib7Yy7hmQlvZRLzb2wdgQ8?e=qsYtmb

Comment: @MrPepeLepeu I don't know why the distance is big. Maybe `ContourEle` unit is not meter. There is a field `ContourUni` whose values are all 1. Check the website you downloded from, and what `1` means. it may be inch.